# Heterogeneous sets in OCaml

Tags: set, ocaml

suppose I have a type defined as

```
type value =
      None
    | Int of int
    | Float of float
    | Complex of Complex.t
    | String of string
    | Char of char
    | Bool of bool
```

and I want to be able to work with `Sets` of these values. From what I understood I have to use the functor to concretize the `Set` module with a concrete type and its associated ordering.

How should I do it in this example? Since `value` cannot be used directly inside the `Set.Make` functor?

Then of course I need to be able to give a full ordering of these values so I should invent something like giving a predefined order to different types, and then ordering them by their effective value.. am I right?

So for example I can decide to have `Int of int < Float of int` and `Int x < Int y` if `x < y`. Is it a practical approach to what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to compare: Int of int < Float of float?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Set.Make](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.Make.html) functor takes the module with signature [Set.OrderedType](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Set.OrderedType.html) :

```
module type OrderedType = sig type t val compare : t -> t -> int end
```

For comparison you can use [`Pervasives.compare`](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALcompare) if you don't have any requirements on the order and results returned by `min_elt`/`max_elt`. So the parameter to the functor can be as simple as :

```
module T = struct type t = value let compare = compare end
```

Comment: But will this allow a comparison between Int of int and Float of float (I think that's what the OP is asking, though he writes: 
Int of int < Float of int ... but I wonder if that's a type as his type specifies Float of float)

Comment: The problem is that I need to provide a way to order different kinds of datatype to be able to use the `Set`, that's why I was wondering if forcing a specific hierarchy (eg `None < Int < Float < Complex ..`) is an acceptable way to do it or if I have to find another way..

Comment: @Jack `Pervasives.compare` will automatically do a sensible comparison; I believe it will implement the hierarchy you propose on its own.  No need to define your own comparison function unless you have particular needs.

Comment: As Michael E said - `compare` is a generic polymorphic structural comparison function - it will define a total ordering on any values (by magic) - use it unless you have a specific requirement on ordering (in case of `Set` this only influences the `min_elt` and `max_elt` functions). NB exception to the above : `compare` cannot compare functions and will raise exception at runtime.

Comment: Can anyone explain *why* Set needs a total ordering? I understand the need for equality but not every set needs to be a total order.